# What are the types of responses in .net web service calling into android app?

Tags: .net, android, web-services

Can any one provide me samples or code snippet of types of responses in .net web serives?

Thanks,
nag.

Answer (score 0):

.NET web services follow the WDSL standard, so you should probably look into that.

Responses are commonly in [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) format, this is XML.

Comment: if service returns DataSet so could you please tell me how to read DataSet and bind into android gridview?